# As of August 2017, how much monero has been mined out of the total supply?

Tags: mining, emission-curve

As of today 2017-08, how much monero has been mined out of the total supply? Is there a website where you can check this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually just https://moneroblocks.info/ shows "Emission" in top right corner, so looks like it is about 14.9M

Answer (score 3):

yshurik is correct, current emission is on https://moneroblocks.info/.

In addition, total coins to be issues (eventually!) can be gotten from coinwarz: https://www.coinwarz.com/cryptocurrency/coins/monero (as well as much other useful info).

Answer (score 1):

As of august 2017, total emission is approximately 14.962175 million monero (), increasing at a rate of roughly 4780 (720 times the current block reward of about 6.64 monero) monero a day. https://moneroblocks.info/tx/2b192d6739c31cf973cdec78a715724ef56e3d16090e6d1fd1a58efcdadbb359 is the current top block for reference. This page shows both current emission and block reward.

At any time, you can ask `monerod` to calculate the amount of Monero emitted so far. For example, on current testnet (979765 is the current chain height):

`print_coinbase_tx_sum 0 979765
Sum of coinbase transactions between block heights [0, 979765) is 13284059.793703353599 consisting of 13281707.066664487079 in emissions, and 2352.727038866520 in fees`

This will go through the blockchain and output the total mined Monero found. Note that since this scans all the blocks, it is a slow command.

Here, we see the total emission so far on testnet is 13281707.066664487079 monero. Try it on mainnet!

Comment: screenshot of how this looks in your terminal for reference?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you're asking for a picture of how the text I copied above is rendered on my particular terminal, I have to decline, unless there is a good reason I cannot see.

Comment: yea just screenshot of the command and the output. you can black out any sensitive stuff obviously. i just wanted to see how its done. if not, thats fine. thanks tho.

Comment: The comand is exactly as I said above: print_coinbase_tx_sum 0 979765. Then adapt for the current height. No screenshot as this does not bring anything to make up for the potential privacy leak.